# Should we create indexes for the fields which are part of mongoexport command?

Tags: mongodb

I am working on a existing Java J2EE application , which is using Mongodb very extensively .

The Application has got some scripts .sh files (bash files ) which runs daily at some point of time whose responsibility is to execute mongoexport command as shown below

```
mongoexport --csv -o /tmp/people.csv -d school -c people -f firstName,lastName,telephone,email
```

My question is that , do i need to create indexes on the collection named people for the `fields firstName,lastName,telephone,email`

**Will this add any advantage on mongodb ?? Or creating indexes on these fields is not necessary at all ??**

So please let me know

Should we create indexes  for the  fields which are part of  mongoexport command ?

Comment: Indexes will help only when searching/sorting. I don't think they would speed up export process itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mongoexport` will run in O(N) time (with or without an index) because you're exporting all the records in the collection (e.g. requires a scan on the collection). As mentioned in a comment, indexes are only needed to speed up searching, sorting, and maybe aggregations.

Comment: would passing a query object to `mongoexport` in order to reduce the number of documents exported improve the efficiency of the export operation?

Comment: I would imagine the answer is yes